# Problem trying to apply De Morgan's Laws

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic

I'm trying to use De Morgan's Law to demonstrate an equivalence but I'm running into a problem when I try to apply it

De Morgan's Law states that ~(P V Q) == ~P ^ ~Q

However when I try to apply this to the following proposition:

~(~P V Q) == ~~P ^ ~Q == P ^ ~Q

I end up with truth tables that aren't equivalent

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious here, but I've been knocking my head against a wall trying to figure out what it is

Any help would be appreciated!

(Here are the truth tables I'm getting)

| P | Q | ~ P V Q | P ^ ~Q |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| T | T | T | F |
| T | F | F | T |
| F | T | T | F |
| F | F | T | F |

Comment: can you write out the truth tables you are getting to show why you think they are not equivalent?

Comment: Hey, yes definitely! I just edited the post

Comment: They are the same! The *negation* of column 3 is column 4.

Comment: Oooooh hahaha that was starting me straight in the face. I knew I was missing something obvious. I've been solving problems for hours and can't think very well right now

Anyway thank you very much!

Comment: To use MathJax for similar questions, you want "\lnot, \lor," and "\land."

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem actually.
The fourth column is equivalent to the negation of the third column.
The problem that you have, is that you forgot that you want
$ \lnot (\lnot P \lor  Q)$  and not $\lnot P \lor Q$.